# Display two fields in one line and one just if necessary

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a standard report with jaspersoft studio.
I want to display two fields in one column (which works already). The second field in the column should just be displayed if it has data (which works too). But It seems that if the second field is not displayed it still takes up space. Or at least the first field isn't vertically aligned in the middle.

I put both in a frame and made them float. Any ideas how to make it align in the middle in the third screenshot?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I used some logic and it works but it seems somehow the second field still takes up space although it is not displayed anymore

Comment: Did you try StretchWithOverflow?

Comment: Yes both fields stretch with overflow. Both have stretch type "No Stretch". When I change the stretch type just the first field is displayed

Comment: You can try this: if you have two fields to display both values at one textField (it will be A), if you have only one field you are displaying the another textField (B) and hide the A. At first case the B is hidden. I hope it is clear :)

Comment: But using expression with ternary operator should work too. And this way is a simpler

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple but effective :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876298/alex-k) pointed out I just copied the first textfield again and put It over the old frame. When there is no data in the second field I hide the frame and show the textfield. When there is data in the second field I hide the textfield and show the frame.

[image]